# Using Java regex to select HL7 data from file

Tags: java, regex, hl7

I guess this is fairly simple but I am struggling with it.  I have a text file with multiple HL7 messages.  I need to break this file apart and write each message to a separate file.
  The simplified structure is as follows with a blank line after the second (inbound) message.  I have highlighted the message content in bold.  Note, however that the messages can finish with a variety of characters

11:37:58:425 ----------------------------------------------------------->>> Outbound >>> **MSH|^~\&|CERNERPM||ADT^A08||P|2.3 EVN|A08||||| PID|1||NK1|PV1| ZPD||SED** 11:37:58:457 <<< Inbound <<<------------------------------------------------------------ **MSH|^~\&|A|CA08**

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Will an algorithm work for you? I am not good with Java so wont take that risk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [library for HL7](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/). It's easier.